# How would a time-traveler maximize their profits with minimal impact on history?

Tags: alternate-history, time-travel

A time traveler has a time machine that will take him back to any point in the past once, and they may choose to return to the present or stay. They have $100 in your possession, nothing more, and can only take with them what they can carry on a dolly, let's say 250 lbs. They have the skills and education of an average first-world citizen, and can speak the modern language of your choosing. What would be the best way they would maximize their profits, while attempting to reduce the ramifications of whatever the time traveler chose to do. Be specific, giving exact years and an exact total dollar amount in present 2019 dollars. Remember, today's US currency is only legal tender back until 2013, though any US currency from 1861 onward remains legal to this day.

Here was my guess, but I'm sure there's a much better way: I would buy \$100 of Aluminum today, weighing 125 lbs, and go back to 1852 where the price of aluminum was \$544/lb. This was just before the Deville process, the first industrial process to refine aluminum, dramatically reduced the price of the metal. The price of gold at this time was \$304/lb. Purchasing 225 lbs of gold, I would return to the present selling at ~\$1500/lb and making $330,000.

Profit ratio: 3300:1

Though this is significantly better than simply abusing inflation or the increasing price of gold, it is by no means the best the time traveler can do given stocks and real estate. What do you think the best way would be?

Comment: I would buy some bitcoins

Comment: Please note we adhere to a strict "one question per post" policy. And the question shall be well focused and measurably answerable.

Comment: This is too open ended. And also incredibly hard to answer. I've not the data on what would happen if there is an influx of aluminium in the past. I'd hazard a guess that very few people, if any, would be able to say *exactly* (or *close enough*) what would happen. It's much better to focus on something like "how do I profit with time travel with minimal side effects". This is tighter and easier to answer. May need a bit more than just that, though. [You can post the question in the Sandbox](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7183/) before the main site.

Comment: Buy bank of Ireland shares after they crashed the day before the government announced a package to save it (sometime around March 2009 I think), they were selling for pennies & bounced something like a thousand fold the following day iirc

Comment: Buy bank of Ireland shares after they crashed the day before the government announced a package to save it (sometime around March 2009 I think), they were selling for pennies & bounced something like a thousand fold the following day iirc ~ [checked](https://www.google.com/search?rlz=1C1NHXL_enGB711GB711&tbm=fin&sxsrf=ACYBGNQ62Zcym2Cld5zDmBrwtYy2wO0SIQ:1575982455982&q=LON:+BIRG&stick=H4sIAAAAAAAAAONgecRowS3w8sc9YSn9SWtOXmPU5OIKzsgvd80rySypFJLmYoOyBKX4uXj10_UNDVPiLS0NTAtMeBaxcvr4-1kpOHkGuQMA6z4jJEkAAAA#scso=_gZXvXZiXCJLnxgPuzb6YCw7:0), not that good but buy low in March & sell in October 2009.

Comment: From the Help Center on [what not to ask](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask): "avoid asking subjective questions where your answer is provided along with the question, and you expect more answers."

Answer (score 2):

I would change the Dollars to Euros and then travel back to 2010 and change it to Bitcoins. In May 2010, somebody bought two pizzas for 10000 Bitcoins. That's 73 Million Dollars today (but could soon be much more or much less). Two pizzas cost something around 15-20 Dollars so I could use the remaining 80-85 Dollars to actually buy Bitcoins. Maybe I'd get another 20000 Bitcoins for a total value of over 200 million today-Dollars. Since the Bitcoin price is pretty low now, I could also wait a bit and maybe have a chance to sell them for half a billion Dollars.

I don't think, that would change history a lot. If anything at all, somebody would write a Wikipedia article about some unknown person that bought 30000 Bitcoins in the early days and would be quite wealthy if he'd sell them.

Answer (score 1):

Your second question depends on how causality would work and is largely up to how you construct your fictional universe.  Generally, time travel breaks down into one of two main paradoxes:  The Grandfather Paradox and the Bootstrap Paradox.

For both scenarios, imagine a billards table with the curious phenomena that each pocket is actually wormhole to a past point at the center of the table.  For the purposes of description, lets say you are only hitting the 8 ball with the cue ball and you can perfectly time it so the portal opens up as the 8 ball crosses mid-point of the table.

In our first scenario, we shoot the 8 ball across the width of the table for  a bank shot into the side pocket.   As the ball crosses center line, the time portal opens up and the future!Ball emerges and knocks the present!Ball off trajectory such that neither present nor future balls enter a pocket and come to a dead stop.   Congratulations, we have violated physics and/or proved alternate time lines are a thing.   This is the Grandfather Paradox.

First, we have created something from nothing (future!Ball is identical in every way to present!ball except a slight age difference) as well as added energy to the universe (there are some hard rules about doing these things) and yet, we never started the time travel for our present ball.   There is no link between the effect of future ball on present ball or the cause of present ball leading to future ball.   Since we didn't sink Present!Ball, Future ball should not exist and one of many corrections may take place:  It may be proof that alternative time lines exist and that while my shot never sank, in another universe it did, and the crossing of center created two parallel universes that diverge from this point...  in theory this would happen from every decision everyone makes creating an infinitely growing infinite multiverse of possibilities.  Or the future!ball will poof out of existence since there was never a reason for it to exist in the first place.   Worst case scenario is that the Universe does whatever is the time-space continuum of the Blue Screen of Death (likely with Fire raining from the sky, rivers and seas boiling, 40 years of darkness, earthquakes, volcanos, dead rising from the grave, human sacrafices, cats and dogs **living together** and other mass hysterical symptoms.  Ask your doctor if Grandfather Paradox is right for you.).

Then we have the BootStrap Paradox.  We start with the same scenario, but in this one, the portal opens and future!ball emerges in a way that it knocks present!ball into the quarter pocket, which takes it back to the past.  Future!ball is definitely present!ball and briefly, the timeline intersected with itself.   This is less reality bending as the Grandfather Paradox as it follows all the rules of physics in that all matter is consevered, but not in the correct order of events, as future!ball is created before present!ball is destroyed and changed itself.   In effect, you can travel to the past, but the only changes you can cause are the ones that already happened... because they will happen in your future in the past.   As the Oracle once noted, it can really bake your noodle.

In a Grandfather paradox, changing the past does cause changes to the original future.  Where as in the Bootstrap Paradox, changing the past causes the original future.

The Back to the Future series works on Grandfather Paradox (and shows the scenario that lent it's name to the paradox, if one generation removed.   Marty goes back in time and accidentally causes his parents to never meet... and the critical moment of their relationship is in danger of never happening, thus Marty will be erased from existence, and the second film shows this happening to Biff (a deleted scene shows old!Biff fade from reality after traveling back to the present in the time machine).

Gargoyles is an excellent user of the Bootstrap paradox, which is on full display in Vows and Avalon, part 2.  The former is the first time travel episode and sets it up to show this is the only rule of time travel.   History is fixed... your position in time and space is not.   Avalon part 2 uses this for a pretty awesome clip show of sorts (most of the scenes were already shown in past episodes, but the new scenes are blended in to give context.  Part one uses a different time travel element to basically do the same thing for the heroes of the three part serial.  Namely, an hour on the titular island is a day for the rest of the world.).   A later episode would have the fact that time travel can never change the past to change the future as a plot point.

Answer (score -1):

Step 1, find out when there was a big lottery jackpot that was not cracked and which numbers where used.

Step 2, get the cash. You can use the identity of some ancestor if you need to.

Step 3, keep all the cash